# opengl : Running at least 25 windows with different Draw callback

Tags: opengl, c, window-management

I need to run at least 25 windows concurrently with each window rendering a different game state.
I am storing all the 25 game states in the array of type GameState allGameStates[25].

For each of the window, i am currently doing this to register a different draw callback for each of the 25 windows.

```
 glutCreateWindow(title);
 glutDisplayFunc(allGameStates[i].Draw);
```

The issue here is that glutDisplayFunc requires a parameter of type function ptr, and i cannot pass in a member function ptr.(i am using GLUT which is in C)

It is not feasible to make the Draw function static as i require the Draw function to render differently accordingly to the other variables in the game state object.

How do i overcome this problem?

Comment: Does this game need to be playable? That sounds like a recipe for disaster. If you enable VSYNC you'll basically only get 2 FPS in your application in the best case ;)

Comment: Luckily for my case ,only 1 window is to be shown to the user at any point in time so vsync is not required.Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`glutDisplayFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node46.html):

> Before the callback, the current window is set to the window needing to be redisplayed

This means that inside the display callback, you can call [`glutGetWindow()`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node18.html) to find out which window is being drawn to.

This means that you *can* use a static member function as the display callback;  just have that static member function figure out which window is being drawn to, and map from that window to its particular game state object instance, and then call a non-static member function on that instance.

Comment: You Sir , is a Genius